# Why calling an async function in JS is not blocking?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Take a look at the following code:

```
function promised() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('Timeout'), 1000);
    });
}

async function awaited()
{
  const r = await promised();
  console.log('Line 10: ' + r);
  return r;
}

function start() {
  const r = awaited();
  console.log('Line 16: ' + r);
}

start();

console.log("All done");
```

When you run this code, you'll get:

```
Line 16: [object Promise]
All done
Line 10: Timeout
```

But I was expecting to get:

```
Line 10: Timeout
Line 16: Timeout
All done
```

My expectation was that `await` should have blocked the execution on line 9. But it seems it does not! My question is why?

Comment: `awaited` execution pauses, `start`'s does not as it is not an async method with an `await` statement. Async methods don't ever block, that is their main purpose to not block. Synchronous functions block, hence why it is advised not to use methods like sync ajax requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Async/Await patterns in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677043/understanding-async-await-patterns-in-javascript)

Comment: If you really want to behave the code like synchronous code (what you call blocking), you would've to use async for all functions up to the calling function and await the result of the those async functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your code as:

```js
    function promised() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("Timeout"), 1000);
      });
    }
    
    async function awaited() {
      const r = await promised();
      console.log("Line 10: " + r);
      return r;
    }
    
    function start() {
      const r = awaited();
      // r here is a promise, so you need to call then to wait until
      // awaited is finished.
      return r.then(d => console.log("Line 16: " + d));
    }
    
    start().then(() => console.log("All done"));
```

result:

> // Line 10: Timeout
>
> // Line 16: Timeout
>
> // All done

Comment: Thanks for the post, but it seems `async` and `await` are just fancy words for the same `Promise` concept. They are not blocking at all!!!

Comment: @Mehran No. `const r = await promised();` this line pauses until it is done. `console.log("Line 10: " + r);` will not be executed until it is done. With promise, `console.log("Line 10: " + r);` will be executed.

Comment: @Mehran: That's basically right. `async/await` are just syntactic sugar on top of promises.

Comment: It would be nice to extend the answer to include an answer for 'why', so it helps for future Googlers.

Comment: @dereli which "why" part?

Comment: The question is: *Why* calling an async function in JS is not blocking? ;)

Comment: @dereli That needs a blog post to answer.. That is a design part. I think here OP's question was why the expected output is not coming. I tried to show the OP what needs to be done to get that. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900719/why-calling-an-async-function-in-js-is-not-blocking/51900797?noredirect=1#comment90752552_51900719) comment in addition to this answer added some good points too. :)

Comment: As you wish sir, mine was a suggestion.

Comment: @dereli I am not a sir.. I am trying to convey the way I understand.. comments are always welcome.. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178272/discussion-between-dereli-and-arup-rakshit).